# javascript finding part of a string

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

I'm not very used to Javascript so I'm having trouble manipulating strings...

If I have something like /folder1/folder2/folder3/ , how do I parse it so I end up with just the current folder, e.g. "folder3" ?

Thanks!

Comment: come on ?! did you search before asking this kind of a question ?!

Comment: var parts = URL.split("/"); alert(parts[parts.length-2]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `split` function to retrieve all subpaths:

```
var path = '/folder1/folder2/folder3/';
var paths = path.split('/');
var pathNeeded = paths[paths.length - 2];
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/WmNCG/)

Comment: While I was typing in the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 3):

```
var folderName = str.match(/(folder\d+)\/$/)[1];
```

Should do it.

Explanation of the regex:

```
(      -> Start of capture group. We want a capture group because we just want 
          the folder name without the trailing slash.           
folder -> Match the string "folder"
\d+    -> Match one or more digits
)      -> End of capture group. This lets us capture strings of the form 
          "folderN", where N is a number.              
\/     -> Escape forward slash. We have to escape this because / is used to 
          represent the start and end of a regex literal, in Javascript.              
$      -> Match the end of the string.
```

The reason we are selecting the second element of the array (at index 1) is because the first element contains the complete string that was matched. This is not what we want; we just want the capture group. We only have one group that we captured, and so that is the second element.

Answer (score 2):

Well, just because it's an option (though not necessarily sane):

```
var string = '/folder1/folder2/folder3/',
    last = string.replace(/\//g,' ').trim().split(/\s/).pop();
    console.log(last);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SsUjh/).

Comment: +1, that's actually pretty neat, and works with or without the trailing slash, and regardless of the last folders name. Was trying to think of a way to do this, but all I could come up with was just removing the last slash.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I threw the `replace()` and `trim()` in there; it just *feels* a little icky (for some unknown reason, but seeing the `length - 2` in the alternatives felt just as bad); but thank you! =D

Answer (score 1):

How stable is the format of that string?
With a trailing slash you will need the next to last item

```
var parts = URL.split("/"); alert(parts[parts.length-2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str    = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/",
    folder = str.substring(0, str.length - 1).split('/').pop();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9uQmU/)

Answer (score 1):

The `split` function transform your string into an array using the supplied parameter as a delimiter.

Therefore:

```
var parts = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/".split("/");
```

Will result in `parts` being equal to:

```
["", "folder1", "folder2", "folder3", ""]
```

You could then access each item using:

```
parts[0] // returns ''
parts[1] // returns 'folder1'
parts[2] // returns 'folder2'
```

.. and so on. Read more on split here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following:

```
var myString = '/fold1/fold2/fold3';
var myArray = myString.split('/');
var last_element = myArray[myArray.length - 1];
```

See the doc [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: @mplungjan
True, i didn't realized when I saw the post in first place.
A check should be done here, to see if there is a slash or not, so he can use substr on this one.
The answer of DavidThomas is actually the best.